# Storyboards: Open UIViewController from storyboard as popover from image in UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, ios, uistoryboardsegue

I have a Custom UITableViewCell class and the custom cell has an image button in it that is linked back to a method on the cell class. When this method is triggered, I want to launch an orphaned UIViewController from the storyboard inside a popover. I've tried several techniques for doing this. Interface Builder will not compile if I add the UIViewController as a segue from the button on the prototype cell. Does anyone have any suggestions?

UPDATE: I Got it working with the following:

```
UITableView *tv = (UITableView *) self.superview;
UITableViewController *vc = (UITableViewController *) tv.dataSource;

UIStoryboard *storyboard = vc.storyboard;
UIViewController *actionView = [storyboard          
     instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ActionView"];

popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                                          initWithContentViewController:actionView];
popoverController.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 416);

[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.actionButton.bounds      
    inView:self.actionButton
permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` from `UIStoryboard` to pick up any view controller if you have it identified correctly.  (Since the easiest way to get a reference to the storyboard is from some view controller that already came from it, you may want to have the cell notify the current controller to do this...that depends on how your objects are connected.)

Comment: yup that works but I need to anchor and provide directionality to the button in the Custom table cell?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that sentence, but I'll make a guess.... :) If you use a notification from the cell, and the view controller listens for that, you can pass a reference to the cell as the notification object or you can populate the userinfo dictionary so that the VC has access to anything the cell knows.